# save data without any extra sign added to the data and separated by a tab character?

Tags: r

actually I am trying to save my data using the following command but the problem is that it adds some columns and signs which I don't want

lets say this is my data and I want to have it saved like

```
v1              v2
    phenzine    2.376140e-05
    dnium bte   2.423254e-05
    trene       2.438986e-05
    tilli       2.495574e-05
    tnolone     2.511859e-05
```

output with a tap separated between two columns in txt

```
        phenzine    2.376140e-05
        dnium bte   2.423254e-05
        trene       2.438986e-05
        tilli       2.495574e-05
        tnolone     2.511859e-05
```

note that I did remove the row names as well like

```
rownames(df) <- NULL
```

what I do is

```
write.table(df, file= "~/Desktop/df.txt", sep="\t" )
```

but it appears like below

```
"V1"   "V2"
"1"             "phenzine"    2.376140e-05
"2"            "dnium bte"   2.423254e-05
 "3"           "trene"       2.438986e-05
"4"            "tilli"       2.495574e-05
"5"            "tnolone"     2.511859e-05
```

Is there any idea how to prevent such output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should export your data with

```
write.table(df, file= "~/Desktop/df.txt", sep="\t", row.names=F, quote=F)
```

By default, `row.names` are exported (hence the first "column" (without heading) you are getting) and character strings are surrounded by quotes.

Doing `row.names(df) <- NULL` doesn't change that, it just changes the `row.names` into `1` to `length(df)` (or just does nothing if the `row.names` were already just the row numbers)

Comment: thanks that is already good to remove the rownames but still "" is around the first column and not going away